# How to nest functions in codeigniter for more pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

What i am trying to achieve is a blog system in codeigniter, as it stands i have an index page for the blog posts which i have used the index() function within the controller therefore i can access this via url/admin/blog i also had a function for editing the posts which works like so edit($id = NULL) so that i am handling the individual post to edit. This works in the url like so url/admin/blog/edit/1 therefore i currently have a structure like so

```
class Blog extends Admin_Controller {

   public function index() {
       // Handle the page output
   }

   public function edit($id = NULL) {
       // Handle the edit page form
   }

}
```

So far everything works fine, i am outputting the blog posts, i am able to edit, save and/or delete them. Now i would like to look into handling the comments, Now i can display all the comments in a table with creating another function within the controller like this:

```
public function comments() {
   // Output the comments with the ability to edit and delete
}
```

However, I now want to have an edit option like before, but if i do the following it doesn't work:

```
public function comments() {
    // Output the comments with the ability to edit and delete

    function edit($id = NULL) {
      // Edit form and submission page
    }
}
```

I want to find a way that i can somehow nest this page in the controller so that my url works like this:

url/admin/blog/comments/edit/1

I am using the latest version of codeigniter i just don't know how to place the function for the page as clearly the way i'm attempting to nest it, is invalid.

Can anyone help?

Comment: maybe i'm not understanding the question but why don't you just make a separate method like "editcomments"  url/admin/blog/editcomments/1

Comment: `url/Class/Method/Parameters [, val1, val2, so on]` to further nestings you need to use parameters instead nested function which won't work what you are expecting.

Comment: thats a good idea, thanks. i can do a rewrite rule to make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Using that URL, the function `comments` will get `edit/1` as 2 parameters
Try this -

```
public function comments($edit=NULL, $id=NULL) 
{
    if($edit != NULL && $id != NULL) 
    {
        // Edit form and submission page
    }
}
```